# Is it possible to create a pointer to a non-static member-function in C++?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I was wondering if it's possible to create and use a pointer to a non-static member-function. When I compile my code without the pointer to the member-function being static, it gives a compilation error.

Thanks...

Comment: Maybe you should show us a short extract of your code so that we can understand your issue better. Don't forget to mention the compilation error.

Comment: actually I need to use a function pointer give in a C header file. tht func pointer should point to a member function in my C++ header.
when i invoke a function in tht C lib(i need to pass func pointer to my member function).How to do this?

Comment: Function pointers and static member function pointers are compatible, however non-static member function pointers have a hidden `this` parameter and are incompatible.

Comment: @Jesse: There's a lot more to non-static members than just a hidden `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create pointer to member functions in C++. See this FAQ: [pointers-to-members](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)

Comment: actually I need to use a function pointer give in a C header file. tht func pointer should point to a member function in my C++ header.
when i invoke a function in tht C lib(i need to pass func pointer to my member function).How to do this?

Comment: @Yogi You can't. All instances of a class share its functions, a pointer to this address alone isn't enough to know which instance should be called. The general solution (say in the win32 API) is to pass a static function around and store the this pointer somewhere so that it can be accessed in the static function and forwarded from there.

Answer (score 2):

In short: Yes, it's possible, and no, it doesn't do what you think.

The crucial fact is that non-static member functions are not functions (just like a Douglas-fir is not a fir). They are *member* functions, and that's something different. They can only be invoked on a given object instance.

Thus in order to call the member function `X::foo()` of a given instance `X a;`, i.e. to perform the call `a.foo()`, you need both the information that you want to use `X::foo()`, and that you want to invoke it on the instance `a`. The former is provided by a *pointer-to-member-function*, which *is not a pointer*, and the latter is provided by an instance pointer or reference:

```
struct X { int foo(bool, char); };  // class definition

X a;          // an instance
X * p = &a;   // just for demonstration

int (X::*)(bool, char) ptmf = &X::foo;   // pointer-to-member-function
```

Now to invoke:

```
(a.*ptmf)(false, 'a');
(p->*ptmp)(true, 'z');
```

In a nutshell: `foo` alone does not let you call anything. The callable entity is the **pair** `(&X::foo, a)`, which lets you call `a.foo()`.

Comment: actually I need to use a function pointer give in a C header file. tht func pointer should point to a member function in my C++ header.
when i invoke a function in tht C lib(i need to pass func pointer to my member function).How to do this?

Comment: @Yogi in C there is no concept of "member function", so no "pointer to non-existent concept" exist.

What you can do is write a plain function taking one extra paramenter that is the object pointer to be used to call the member function.

Comment: If you need the pointer to function for a C program, the function itself must be `extern "C"`.  Some compilers don't detect this error, but others will; the C++ standard requires a diagnosis of some sort.